# Angular2 stops (click) working when using DomSanitizer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm using Angular2 with typescript.

I have a pipe that works regarding rendering the HTML fine.
Problem is the **DomSanitizer** seems to stop the (click) event from working.

When I check the HTML in the console.log (F12) the (click) code seems to be there and not stripped out.

But when I click the link it does nothing.

**This is an example of the link (it calls a function in my component):**

```
<a (click)="recordLinkClick()" target="_blank" href="#">Test link</a>
```

**This is the pipe:**

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe {

  constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  public transform(value: string, type: string = 'html'): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl': return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }

}
```

**This is the line of HTML:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="selectedArticle.body | safe: 'html'"></div>
```

Let me know if you need to see anymore code.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? I am having the same issue and not getting any solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a (click)="recordLinkClick()" target="_blank" href="#">Test link</a>
```

If you want this anchor to be put in by `innerHTML` angular will *not* register it without you *compiling* the html before putting it into the DOM.

The steps for dynamically compiling html for angular 2 are covered here : [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

Comment: seems like I need to compile the html before putting it into the DOM. Not sure how yet though. Any ideas?